# Why does psql -f COPY FROM STDIN fail when -c succeeds?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgres-12

Using `psql` with `COPY FROM STDIN` works fine when executed via `-c` (inline command) but the same thing fails if `-f` (script file) is used. I've created a Docker-based test to demonstrate below; tested on MacOS w/ zsh and Debian w/ bash.

I was unable to find any relevant documentation on *why* this would be but I imagine it has to do with `psql`'s special `\copy` functionality. Can someone help illuminate me?

```sh
# create test data
echo "1,apple
2,orange
3,banana">testdata.csv

# create test script
echo "drop table if exists fruits;
create table fruits (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR);
copy fruits from stdin with delimiter as ',' csv;
select * from fruits">testscript.pg

# create network
docker network create pgtest

# run Postgres server
echo "starting postgres server"
PG_CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -d --name=pgtest --rm --network=pgtest -h database -e POSTGRES_USER=user1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass1 -e POSTGRES_DB=db1 -p 6432:5432 postgres:12)

echo "sleeping for 5 seconds (wait for server to start)"
sleep 5
docker logs $PG_CONTAINER_ID

echo "*"
echo "*"
echo "*"
echo "run psql script using inline with -c"
cat testdata.csv | docker run -i --rm --network=pgtest postgres:12 psql postgres://user1:pass1@database:5432/db1 -c "$(cat testscript.pg)"

echo "*"
echo "*"
echo "*"
echo "run psql script using file with -f"
cat testdata.csv | docker run -i -v $PWD:/host --rm --network=pgtest postgres:12 psql postgres://user1:pass1@database:5432/db1 -f /host/testscript.pg

# stop server
echo "*"
echo "*"
echo "*"
docker stop $PG_CONTAINER_ID
docker rm $PG_CONTAINER_ID
```

The output of the psql commands look like this:

```
*
*
*
run psql script using inline with -c
NOTICE:  table "fruits" does not exist, skipping
 id |  name  
----+--------
  1 | apple
  2 | orange
  3 | banana
(3 rows)

*
*
*
run psql script using file with -f
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
psql:/host/testscript.pg:5: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "select * from fruits"
CONTEXT:  COPY fruits, line 1, column id: "select * from fruits"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, (execution with `-c`), the copy data are read from standard input.

In the second case (execution with `-f`), the input file acts as input to `psql` (if you want, standard input is redirected from that file). So PostgreSQL interprets the rest of the file as `COPY` data and complains about the content. You'd have to mix the `COPY` data in with the file:

```
/* script with copy data */
COPY mytable FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv');
1,item 1,2021-11-01
2,"item 2, better",2021-11-11
\.

/* next statement */
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD newcol text;
```

Comment: That is fascinating -- is there a way to mark an EOF of that data within the script file or is it just that the entire remainder is considered `stdin`?

Comment: I have added how you mix copy data with SQL code.